I am trying to upgrade my Great expectation module from 0.16.x to 1.2.4. While using the existing Data Context Configuration i am getting an error
The way we are configure, the main module calls a http API to get a config. The code is running in the older version like (0.16.x)
While my code is able to create the context using the existing configuration, but not able to do validation while i am trying to build the docs.
Previously we were using BaseDataContext which got replaced with get_context for the current version
from great_expectations.data_context.types.base import FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults, DataContextConfig, 
DataConnectorConfig
from great_expectations.data_context.data_context.context_factory import get_context
datasource_config = DataConnectorConfig(
    class_name="Datasource",
    module_name="great_expectations.datasource",
    execution_engine={
        "module_name": "great_expectations.execution_engine",
        "class_name": class_name,
    },
    data_connectors={
        "default_runtime_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "RuntimeDataConnector",
            "module_name": "great_expectations.datasource.data_connector",
            "batch_identifiers": ["default_identifier_name"],
        },
    },
)

data_context_config = DataContextConfig(fluent_datasources={"abc": datasource_config},
store_backend_defaults=FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults(
root_directory=report_op)
)
context = get_context(project_config=data_context_config)
Validation error:
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'ge_cloud_id': ['Unknown field.'], 'expectation_suite_name': ['Unknown field.'], 'data_asset_type': ['Unknown field.']}
I am not sure how the ge_cloud_id, data_asset_type can be set.
I tried with the alternative for the current version but not able to get pass the error
